# Entails symbol without an antecedent?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know that A |= B means that if whenever A is true, then B must also be true. But while doing practice problems I came across a entails without an antecedent.

> If |= A and |= ~B, then |= ~(A ↔ B)

What is the meaning for entails without an antecedent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol: $\vDash A$ means that the formula $A$ is [universally valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity) (or a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)) in propositional logic), i.e.

> true under every interpretation.

Regarding your example:

> if $\vDash A$ and $\vDash \lnot B$, then $\vDash \lnot (A \leftrightarrow B)$,

this amounts to saying that, if $A$ and $B$ are *tautologies*, also $\lnot (A \leftrightarrow B)$ is.

You can prove it using truth-table.